# Common logarithm question

Tags: logarithms

I'm studying logarithms and am doing an exercise where you're supposed to evaluate the solutions of common logarithms without using a calculator. I'm very stuck on this one particular question. I know the answer because I used my calculator, but I'd like to know how to solve it without one. The question is $$\log\left(\frac{10}{\sqrt[\large3]{10}}\right)$$

How do I solve this without a calculator? (Please provide a step-by-step solution, this has really confused me.)

Comment: Can you write $10/\root3\of {10}$ as $10^x$ for some $x$? If so, what would $\log 10^x$ be?

Comment: @DavidMitra I got as far as $10(10^{-\frac13})$ but don't know where to go from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{10}{\sqrt[3]{10}} = \frac{10}{10^{1/3}} = 10^{1-1/3} = 10^{2/3}$$

Now, what would the logarithm (assuming base 10) of that final expression be?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand why $\frac{10}{10^{1/3}} = 10^{1-1/3}$. Probably me being a moron, but I don't understand how you got there.

Comment: @imulsion The following rule is very good to know: $\frac{x^a}{x^b} = x^{a-b}$. Let $x=10$, $a=1$ and $b=1/3$. (Remember that $10 = 10^1$.)

Comment: I can't believe that I forgot that :facepalm:. Thanks very much for your help though, I will accept your answer when I can

Comment: @imulsion No need to feel stupid, we are all here to learn. :)

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the logarithm of a quotient is the difference of logarithms:
$$log\left(\frac{10}{\sqrt[3]{10}}\right)=log(10)-log(\sqrt[3]{10})=1-log(10^{1/3})=1-\frac {1}{3}\cdot log(10)=1-\frac {1}{3}=\frac {2}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

To get a good understanding of logarithms it is good to realize that
the following two questions are equivalent:

1) What is the logarithm of $a$ on base of $g$? I.e. $\log$$_{g}\left(a\right)=?$.

2) To what power must $g$ be raised to get $a$ as outcome? I.e.
$g^{?}=a$.

Here $a>0$, $g>0$ and $g\neq1$.

So $10^{\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{10}{\sqrt[3]{10}}$ is the same information
as $\log_{10}\frac{10}{\sqrt[3]{10}}=\frac{2}{3}$